# Grails / Spock testing provide stubbed implementation for a service

Tags: grails, testing, spock

Currently i have a Grails Service that actually publishes messages to an AMQP provider. I would like to stub the message publishing by replacing the publish method so that it does not publish to AMQP but stores the messages in a list

Example:

```
class AService {
    EventPublisherService eventPubliserService
    def createSomething() {
        eventPublisherService.publishEvent(..)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to stub the 'createSomethingMethod' in a integration test so i can check the published events later on in a list?

Comment: Why replace just the publishEvent() method and not the whole EventPublisherService object?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `eventPublisherService` with a map of closures, with the keys the names of the methods being mocked.  Then within the closure, you could test the list of messages passed.  Restore the service afterwards so that it does not affect other tests.

```
class AServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    def aService
    def eventPublisherService

    @After
    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
        aService.eventPublisherService = eventPublisherService
    }

    void testSomething() {
        aService.eventPublisherService = [publishEvent: { messages ->
            assert messages.size() == 5
            // etc.
        }]

        // continue testing
    }
}
```